# STL remove doesn't work as expected?

Tags: c++, stl

```
int main()
{

        const int SIZE = 10;
        int a[SIZE] = {10, 2, 35, 5, 10, 26, 67, 2, 5, 10};
        std::ostream_iterator< int > output(cout, " ");
        std::vector< int > v(a, a + SIZE);
        std::vector< int >::iterator newLastElement;

        cout << "contents of the vector: ";
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), output);

        newLastElement = std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 10);
        cout << "\ncontents of the vector after remove: ";
        //std::copy(v.begin(), newLastElement, output); 
                         //this gives the correct result : 2 35 5 26 67 2 5
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), output);
          //this gives a 10 which was supposed to be removed : 2 35 5 26 67 2 5 2 5 10

        cout << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

There are three 10 in the array a.

why does the array v contains a 10 after we remove the all the 10s with remove function.

you can see the compiled output also [here](http://ideone.com/rlxd8)

Comment: By the way, is this comment (`//this gives the correct result : 2 35 5 26 67 2 5 2 5`) what the program really emits? You really meant to say `2 35 5 26 67 2 5`, right?

Comment: yes, absolutly right.Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Actually `std::remove` doesn't remove the item from the container. Quoted from [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/remove.html)

> Remove removes from the range `[first, last)` all elements that are equal to `value`. That is, remove returns an iterator `new_last` such that the range `[first, new_last)` contains no elements equal to `value`. *The iterators in the range `[new_last, last)` are all **still dereferenceable**, but the elements that they point to are **unspecified**.* Remove is stable, meaning that the relative order of elements that are not equal to value is unchanged.`

That is, `std::remove` works with a pair of iterators only and does not know anything about the container which actually contains the items. In fact, it's not possible for `std::remove` to know the underlying container, because there is no way it can go from a pair of iterators to discover about the container to which the iterators belong. So `std::remove` doesn't really remove the items, **simply because it cannot**. The only way to *actually* remove an item from a container is to invoke a member function on that container.

So if you want to remove the items, then use [Erase-Remove Idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove):

```
 v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 10), v.end());
```

---

The [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove) is so common and useful is that `std::list` has added another member function called `list::remove` which produces the same effect as that of the `erase-remove` idiom.

```
 std::list<int> l;
 //...
 l.remove(10); //it "actually" removes all elements with value 10!
```

That means, you don't need to use `erase-remove` idiom when you work with `std::list`. You can directly call its member function `list::remove`.

Answer (score 12):

The reason is that STL algorithms do not modify the size of the sequence. `remove`, instead of actually erasing items, moves them and returns an iterator to the "new" end. That iterator can then be passed to the `erase` member function of your container to actually perform the removal:

```
v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 10), v.end());
```

By the way, this is known as the "erase-remove idiom".

EDIT: I was incorrect. See comments, and Nawaz's answer.

Comment: The answer from [Nawaz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456870/stl-remove-function/6456967#6456967) says that the elements past the new end are unspecified and not necessarily equal to the removed elements, so you're seeing an artifact of a particular implementation. Renaming the function wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: `std::remove` isn't required to `move matching values to the end of the sequence`, as you seem to think.

Answer (score 2):

C++20 introduces a new non-member function [`std::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) that simplifies this task for all standard library containers.

The solution suggested by multiple older answers here:

```
v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 10), v.end());
```

Can now be written as:

```
std::erase(v, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `std::remove` doesn't actually shrink the container, it just moves all the elements down to to fill up the spot used by the "removed" element. For example, if you have a sequence `1 2 3 4 5` and use `std::remove` to remove the value `2`, your sequence will look like `1 3 4 5 5`. If you then remove the value `4`, you'll get `1 3 5 5 5`. At no point does the sequence ever get told to be shorter.